How to change proportions of a model after it's rigged?
I have a mesh and rig of a human made with Makehuman.  I want to shorten the neck on the model, but can't figure out how to do it without having the rig stick out from the body.  My naive approach was simple.  I selected the vertices in the neck, scaled them in Z, moved them down to the shoulder, and moved the head down to the neck. That worked, but the rig now sticks out of the top of the head.  I tried scaling the neck bit of the rigging, but that just changed the size of that segment, and nothing else.
I could simply make another human model in Makehuman with a shorter neck, but it seems there should be a way to do this.
Is it possible to deform the mesh and the rigging at the same time?

When you edit the mesh of a rigged model, you also need to edit the armature (if you don't want to have any bones sticking out). Depending on how serious the changes are, you may have to adjust the weighting of the bones (keyword: weight painting). That is, select the armature, go to Edit mode, and select all head bones and only the head of the neck bone to shorten it. Then move them down as much as needed.

Generally speaking, the procedure could be: use the rig to get the new proportions and pose (maybe scaling neck bone on Local Y axis, and adjusting Head bones if necessary).
When the new pose is ok, apply the armature modifier, so that the mesh is permanently changed in its Rest Pose.
Then select the rig, go to pose mode, select all bones (even hidden ones, turn on all bone layers) and press Ctrl A > Apply pose as rest pose.
Then add to the mesh a new armature modifier targeting the rig.
Some rigs can break after this procedure (if they use Stretch to constraints or other mechanism which rely on fixed values), but generally it works.
Weights will not be affected by this procedure.

Thanks.  This worked for me.
